# How to return SAP error message in excel cell through VBA?

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I wrote an automation script that uses the following SAP GUI:

```
objSess.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "flqaf"
objSess.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
objSess.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 17
objSess.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").CurrentCellColumn = "TEXT"
objSess.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").SelectedRows = "0"
objSess.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cntlALV_CONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").DoubleClickCurrentCell
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_BELNR-LOW").Text = W_BPNumber
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_BELNR-LOW").SetFocus
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_BELNR-LOW").caretPosition = 10
objSess.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
objSess.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
objSess.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
```

Everything works fine, however sometimes the problem aborts in SAP and exactly when that happens I want to capture it by writing the term "error" into an excel cell.

I tried adding this line in vba

```
objSheet.Cells(iRow, 5) = GuiStatusbar.Text
```

As well as

```
objSheet.Cells(iRow, 5) = objSessFindById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text
```

The code still runs fine but my cells in column 5 remain empty. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what "aborts in SAP"? Your code fails on my system, can you post a [complete, minimal and reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I don't understand if your issue comes from Excel or from SAP GUI Scripting, can you isolate the source of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you wait a little.

fo example:

```
...
objSess.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

waitTill = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
While Now() < waitTill
 DoEvents
Wend

if objSess.findById("wnd[0]/sbar").messageType = "E" then 'other types: W, I, S, A
 objSheet.Cells(iRow, 5) = objSessFindById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text 
end if

objSess.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan