# SAP GUI script handling two possible popups when saving

Tags: vba, sap-gui

Created a script for price update on Purchasing Orders (PO's).

A problem occurs if price I'm trying to update is already same on the PO. Then there is nothing to save and *Information* popup windows appears saying "No data change". Here is where the script stops working as recording of the script is based on that new price is different and it can be saved.

I tried  to add if statement to the code but it's not working. It doesn't save when the new price is different and it needs to be saved.
It always chooses Enter and Else statement is not utilized.

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press 'Save on Menu bar

If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then
   If session.findById("wnd[1]").text = "Information" then 
      session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press 'If popup and it's only Information type press Enter

      objSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "No data changed"  'Information that no change has been done

   Else

      session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-VAROPTION1").press  'Save in the popup window

      objSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "Updated" 'Information that the new price has been updated

   End if
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to check out [mcve]

Comment: Hello, I tried to keep it to the minimum now. Hope it's understandable otherwise I'll update it again

Comment: I have corrected the tag [tag:sapscript] to [tag:sap-gui]. That is for SAPScript technology, it's not SAP GUI Scripting

Comment: Could you tell us the values of the variables during your debug?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352648/sap-gui-script-how-to-test-the-presence-of-a-message].  The problem is very similar to this one except for in this example you get the popup from the system when there is nothing to save. On example in the link there is only message in status bar saying "No data change".

Comment: Debug highlightes "End if" in yellow  and Next in blue saying Compile error: Next without for

Comment: By removing `If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]"` Then the script works exactly as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By removing `If session.ActiveWindow.Name = "wnd[1]" Then` the script works as it should

```
   If session.findById("wnd[1]").text = "Information" then 
      session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press 'If popup and it's only Information type then press Enter

      objSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "No data changed"  'Information that no change has been done

   Else

      session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/btnSPOP-VAROPTION1").press  'Save in the popup window

      objSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "Updated" 'Information that the new price has been updated

   End if
```