# Detecting window in SAP GUI script with if condition

Tags: user-interface, sap-gui

There is attached SAP GUI window [image: SAP window].

How I can detect if that window appears? It is not pop up window. Tried code below but it stops without error message and says completed and that window in the picture remains on screen. Everything else before this code works. I need to go just back from that window and then save a production order.

```
If session.findById("wnd[0]").text = "Message log created on" then 
   session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press 'If popup message log appears then press button Back

Else
   session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press 'Save production order

End if

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press 'If previous if sentence is true press save after that
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAP GUI script handling two possible popups when saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393369/sap-gui-script-handling-two-possible-popups-when-saving)

Comment: No, the problem is that the window in my situation is not popup window. And the code on that example may work with popup but it does not work with wnd[0] or there is just some minor mistake.

Comment: Can't you make it work by checking the window title? (`If session.findById("wnd[0]").text = "title of your window" then  ...`) What other solution would you prefer?

Comment: If you mean that the title is "Production order change: Header" it does not work because when you press back it goes to the window which has the same title.

Comment: You can also test the current program and screen number: `If session.Info.Program = "SAPMXXXX" And session.Info.ScreenNumber = 1500 Then` (SAPMXXXX and 1500 are arbitrary). You can see the program name and screen number via the menu System > Status.

Comment: Thanks a lot, above works great! Session info and screen number, I did know that there is so exact naming. Also tabs can be differentiated from that status info.