# Error field not found in SM37 for jobs which don't exist

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui, sap-basis

Good day. I am very new to SAP Scripting and VBA and built the code below with the help of recording my interactions in SAP as well as searching the web. I am trying to schedule adhoc job runs from a list in Excel in SAP system using VBA, but I get errors for jobs that are not found in `SM37`, error happens at this line in code below:

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
```

Finally got the skip to the next iteration working, unfortunately, 2nd error throws the same error message 619 and is not getting skipped forward to the next loop. What seems to be the problem with my code?

Code:

```
    For i = 2 To objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)) = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
            On Error GoTo Handler:
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nsm37"
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkBTCH2170-PRELIM").Selected = False
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkBTCH2170-READY").Selected = False
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkBTCH2170-RUNNING").Selected = False
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkBTCH2170-FINISHED").Selected = False
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkBTCH2170-ABORTED").Selected = False
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBTCH2170-JOBNAME").Text = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value)) 'Original Job Name - 1 is column A, 2 is column B and so on
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBTCH2170-USERNAME").Text = "*"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBTCH2170-FROM_DATE").Text = ""
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtBTCH2170-TO_DATE").Text = ""
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
            objSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Not Found"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[4,12]").SetFocus
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[4,12]").caretPosition = 0
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 30
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtBTCH1180-JOBNAME").Text = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value)) 'Name of the Adhoc Job
            session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtBTCH1180-JOBNAME").caretPosition = 31
            session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkBTCH2170-PRELIM").Selected = True
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBTCH2170-JOBNAME").Text = Trim(CStr(objSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value)) 'Name of the Adhoc Job
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkBTCH2170-PRELIM").SetFocus
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
            objSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value = "AdHoc Released"
Handler:

    On Error GoTo 0
    Next
```

Comment: I think that your description is incorrect, the error probably happens right after line `btn[8]").press` (`F8` key), the field `lbl[4,12]` doesn't exist, because the list screen is not displayed due to the non-existing job. There can be several approaches to solve that. Either you handle the error in VBA, or you detect which screen is displayed after `F8`, etc. Please focus on one precise question. NB: probably any of these questions has been already solved at SO.

Comment: However, it could also be that the current job name is shorter than 28 characters. You can omit the following command entirely, or at least change it as follows:

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtBTCH2170-JOBNAME").caretPosition = 1                                      Otherwise you could also test the following:
on error resume next
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/lbl[4,12]").setFocus
if err.number <> 0 then
   on error goto 0
  ....
else
  on error goto 0
  ...
end if

Comment: @SandraRossi, you hit the spot at pointing where the error was occurring, unfortunately, all the searches I did had different solutions to what was needed in my error, although right now, I am checking if I can capture the exact error message from the message box from SAPGUI when the error is encountered and use it to trigger to skip to the next iteration of the loop, still searching the web on how to do this right now.

Comment: @ScriptMan, I don't think it's the name though, because no matter how long or short I make the name as long as it is within the allowed number of characters for the fields, as long as the job exists, I do not get an error.

Comment: You'd better ask the question "[how to test the presence of a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352648/sap-gui-script-how-to-test-the-presence-of-a-message)" ;-)

Comment: I seem to have been able to at least make 1 instance of skipping to the next iteration using the code below, but if it only works once then encounters the error 619 again on the 2nd error.